# Ошибка при работе алгоритма shuffle

Tags: c++, list

```
const int Size=100;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1000);
int main()
{
list<double>a(Size);
   iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 2);
   shuffle(a.begin(),a.end(),dis(gen));
}
```

Ошибка:`error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<double>' and 'int')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Идем в документацию std::shuffle](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

> ...
>
> ```
> template< class RandomIt, class URNG >
> void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URNG&& g );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Требования к типам
>
> -RandomIt должен соответствовать требованиям ValueSwappable и **RandomAccessIterator**.
>
> -URNG должен соответствовать требованиям UniformRandomNumberGenerator.

Т.е. передаваемые итераторы должны иметь перегруженный operator+, которого нет у итератора std::list, который сам по себе является контейнером с последовательным доступом.

Answer (score 0):

`list` не предоставляет итератор с произвольным доступом, `shuffle` к нему неприменим (оператор `+`, о котором идет речь в сообщении об ошибке, не определен для итератора контейнера `list`).

Воспользуйтесь `vector<double>`.